# Nodejs, how to close child process on parent crash

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have an app.js that start another process with child-process.fork();

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
...
app.set('startedProcesses', {
    queueListener: childProcess.fork('./queueListener.js')
});
app.get('startedProcesses').queueListener.send({action: 'start'});
```

in the queueListener process I start another workers (in the same way, with child-process.fork());

When I start the application with `>node app.js` and I have a crash in the system, then all processes are killed.

The problem is that when I start it with: `>supervisor app.js` or `>forever start app.js` the queueListener process and it's workers are not stopped, and after app.js is restarted these processes are duplicated.

Comment: Could you just check with an if statement.. if(queueListener.connected = true) {} else{skip it}...?

Comment: crash doesn't happen in queueListener or it's workers, it happens in app.

Comment: Why are you using forever and supervisor? Are you executing the app in a Linux environment? If this is the case, I'd recommend using linux services or any bash script. This kind of monitoring tasks are part of the job of sysadmins.

Comment: Yes, the app is on Linux. Thx for the idea with a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, if the parent can't close the children, they can either poll the parent process and then close themselves when they notice that the parent process is gone, or you can spawn an extra child to close the other child processes when the parent crashes and then have the extra child close itself.